# How to use array filter 'where' to select variants without an image?

Tags: arrays, shopify, liquid

I want to create an array from my product object where the variants do not have any images.

```
{% assign test_arr = product.variants | where: 'images.size', 0 %}
```

The 'where' filter should give me a new array that only has 'variants' that do not have an image.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [Shopify Docs for Where](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/filters/array-filters#where), it can only be used with the property value while variant.image itself is an object of **image** type.

> Creates an array including only the objects with a given property
>   value, or any truthy value by default.

Moreover, if the image for variant does not exist, it is *nil*. [Nil - Shopify Docs](https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/liquid/basics/types#nil)

> Nil is a special empty value that is returned when Liquid code has no
>   results. It is not a string with the characters "nil".

So I think the only possible solution is to use for loop and capture or output whatever you need.

```
{% for variant in product.variants %}
    {% if variant.image == nil %}
        {{ variant.title }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```